# Use of Ptr operator?

Tags: assembly, x86

I get confused about this - please can any one tell me how it works ?

```
array db 10,20,30,40

mov eax,DWORD PTR array    ;eax should contains 40302010 (in Little endian.)
```

but this is not working in my computer/system. Please can anyone help me - why is it like that ? In my program it contains some garbage value. Please help me.

Comment: IIUC, PTR is not an operator, DWORD PTR is a qualifier, and [] is an operator.

Answer (score 2):

Your **eax** contains $281E140A. The hexadecimal $28, $1E, $14 and $0A corresponds to your declared elements. for it to say $40302010, your array needs to be:

```
array db $10,$20,$30,$40
```

Comment: please tell me that what is $ symbol actually i'm using MASM611 so it gives me error that $ is undeclared symbol or undefined symbol please elaborate it.....

Comment: Denotes a hexadecimal number. Try **array db 0x10,0x20,0x30,0x40**.

Comment: Or **array db 010h,020h,030h,040h**

Comment: no it is useless beacuse give me some usefull answers actually i have project in which i have to read the wages and salaray form the file for that i'am using the array because salaray is up to 8 digit for that i need the PTR operator to convert the 8 digits in to eax register and then in to a varaibale for forther operation on it so give me some idea that how i convert the 8 digits/elements of the array in to a single variable using PTR oprt or any other ..... THANKS ALOt

Comment: Sounds like you want a **str2int** function, like _atoi_. It's not something you can do automatically with PTR if the salary is in ascii format.